# OpenCart/ocStore 3.x совместно с Bootstrap 5.x и JQuery 3.x

Tags: jquery, opencart, bootstrap5, ocstore

Можно ли для OpenCart/ocStore 3.x сделать тему, базирующуюся на Bootstrap 5 и JQuery 3.7.0 без каких-то модификаций стандартных модулей?

Спрашиваю вот почему. Заглянул в контроллер `catalog/controller/product/product.php` и увидел вот какой кусок кода:

```
            $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/magnific/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js');
            $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/magnific/magnific-popup.css');
            $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/moment/moment.min.js');
            $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/moment/moment-with-locales.min.js');
            $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js');
            $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css');
```

Т.е. подключается та версия JQuery, которая идет в поставке. А именно 2.1.1.

Как вообще лучше поступить для такой вот интеграции?